# Environment that includes a command window

Tags: python, r, matlab, pydev, rstudio

I am looking for a development environment for Python (or for any other language) that includes an command window such as the one in MATLAB or RStudio.

I always liked the fact that you can assign variables and launch function and get quick results without launching the entire script.

I was sure this is also possible in Python but I didn't find this feature yet (I tried PyDev and Pycharm for now...).

I might picked up bad habits from MATLAB but I do think that I am much more productive when I can just load some code from the script and debug my code in real time.

Comment: try ipython, it should be close to what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I am not getting you right, but try out [PyScripter](http://pyscripter.googlecode.com). It has a python interpreter which you can use alongside the actual code editor, it goes hand in hand with the actual code execution.

In the below picture, you can see the interpreter at the bottom.
[image]